# iOS device is not receiving the MDM APNS notification(wakeup call)

Tags: apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have followed the following link http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning and uploaded the generated file to the https://identity.apple.com/pushcert wherein the Push notification certificate has been generated.

I have created the .mobileConfig file using IPCU with the Vendor.p12 file as the identity and could able to install the profile on my iOS device. Profile installation is successful and i could see the console log in the IPCU and also the device is hitting the server and checkin urls mentioned in the profile.

I downloaded the APNS certificate in the PEM format form the portal and installed it in the keychain access. I selected the APNS certificate (APSP:an23.....) and the private key that is associated with the MDM vendor certificate(Am i doing any mistake here???) and exported those into .p12 file. Using this .p12 file i am sending the wakeupcall to the iOS devices by sending  push notification using java-apns library. I am getting feedback that the message is been delivered but the iOS device is not hitting back to the Checkin-url with the Idle status.
Please let me know how to fix this issue ...

Comment: Does the IPCU console log show that the device has received a notification?

Comment: no it doesn't show the information about any notification...

Comment: The following is the IPCU console during the above process


MC: mc_mobile_tunnel starting.
MC: mc_mobile_tunnel shutting down.
MDM: mdmd starting...
MDM: Looking for managed app states to clean up
<Warning>: (com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd) Check-in of Mach service failed. Already active: com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-dev
<Warning>: Unable to bootstrap_check_in() to namedDelegatePort 'com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-dev'. APS connections will not persist past process lifetime.
<Warning>:(com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmd)Check-in of Mach service failed.Already active:

Comment: com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-prod
<Warning>: Unable to bootstrap_check_in() to namedDelegatePort 'com.apple.managedconfiguration.mdmdpush-prod'. APS connections will not persist past process lifetime.
MDM: Network reachability has changed.
MDM: Network reachability has changed.
MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
MDM: Telling MDM Check-In Server about new device token.
MDM: Transaction completed. Status: 200
MDM: mdmd stopping...
profiled: Idled.
profiled: Service stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Is the device able to reach apple via 5223? The device needs to open a connection to receive check in requests. 3g devices should normally be ok, but wifi devices may be blocked.

Comment: Thanks James ... my iOS device is able to receive the Push notifications for Native iOS applications on the device over the WiFi and 3G too. Only when i send the MDM wakeup notification in the form of {"mdm":"XXXXXXXX-5004-43C4-8462-XXXXXXXXXXXX"} then its not been delivered to the iOS device. If i send normal push notification to the iOS device for a particular iOS application in the form of {"aps":{"alert":"This is some fancy message.","badge”:1}}, device receive the notification both on WiFi and 3G network

Comment: James ... I have tested sending the MDM notification both on development and production APNS servers. Do my MDM/APNS certificate could be wrong? But i not getting any error message or feedback from APNS stating my MDM.APNS certificate is invalid... Please guide me